# Detect removal of topics via Push-Diffusion

Tags: push-diffusion

I have subscribed to a tree of topics and am using that to update values in an HTML table . Sometimes new child topics are added and old child topics are removed. I need to keep my UI in sync, new topics are detected when values arrive for an unknown topic, but I cannot discover when a subscribed topic has been removed.

How can I detect when a topic has been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are subscribing to a topic tree using a [topic selector](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.7.2/manual/html/designguide/data/publication/topic_selector_unified.html) such as `?myTopicTreeRoot//`, then you when you place this subscription call, you can also state what would happen in case of a unsubscription, as well as subscription, e.g:

```
session.subscribe("?myTopicTreeRoot//").on({
    open: function(subscription) {
        console.log('Opened subscription for: ' + subscription.selector);
    },
    update : function(update, topic) {
        console.log('Update for ' + topic + ' : ' + update);
    },
    subscribe : function(details, topic) {
         //This will notify you of every new subscription to a topic in your subtree
        console.log('Subscribed to : ' + topic);
    },
    unsubscribe : function(reason, topic) {
        //This will notify you of every unsubscription from a topic in your subtree
        console.log('Unsubscribed from : ' + topic);
    }
});
```

Property functions `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` are called for topic `myTopicTreeRoot` and any descendant, e.g. `myTopicTreeRoot/foo/bar/baz`.

**Importantly**: Any subscription is ended when the topic is removed, which in turn calls `unsubscribe`.

Note that it is better to use the [subscribe](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.7.3/js/Subscription.html) property function. Using the first call to `update` to imply existence of a new topic is unwise if subscribing to stateless topics.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, very helpful!